# Bootstrap 3.0 col-sm-offset-1 is affecting md and lg devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to just set an offset `col-sm-offset-1` and this is also affecting `md` and `lg` devices as well even after setting their offsets to too.
I don't know what is causing this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            Some html here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0">
            Some html here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            Some html here...
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of row div -->
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see an issue of any gaps - have a look at this, I've added border for easy viewing http://www.bootply.com/ucHfOxR7Sm

Answer (score 3):

The offset applies from sm all the way up to max size. That is the point of Bootstraps mobile first approach.

You could try adding col-md-offset-0 to prevent the offset applying to larger sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You code works as intended, but perhaps you are mistaking the margins for an offset? If you want the content to stretch out and fill the page, replace container by container-fluid, like so.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            Some html here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0">
            Some html here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            Some html here...
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of row div -->
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="container-fluid">` is just stretching it.

Comment: do you see a gap **between** the 1st and 2nd divs in md and lg?

Comment: Yes. There is a gap and that is what I am seeking solution for.

Comment: here's a jsfiddle with your code - http://jsfiddle.net/4m4fcmco/1/. Could you post a screenshot of the gap? You can just use the handles on the jsfiddle result section to expand / contract. cheers!

Comment: also, just to cross-check, do you have any other css on the page apart from bootstrap, or just to cross-check, do you mind getting a new copy of the bootstrap css - there is an (extremely) small chance that the md and lg 0 classes have been removed or overwritten.

Comment: also, i'm stretching it a bit :-), you do have a space between col-md-offset-0 and col-lg-offset-0 and not some non-printable character, right?